# problems with accent in mysql client SQuirreL

Tags: mysql, squirrel-sql

I use SQuirreL SQL client Version 3.5.3

I wanted to do an insert of a text with accent like éèà but I get a syntax error. The follow select statement doesn't work:

```
select 'élève';
```

The error is the following:

```
Error: Syntax error or access violation,  message from server: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''élèv' at line 1"
```

when I delete the é and è it works.

Does someone know how I can solve that accent problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried in my version of squirrel:

```
select 'élève' from dual;
```

Its on oracle. It worked without error. You probably need to make sure your connection is set up to handle unicode and that the underlying database supports that character set. Is that syntax even valid for your database? (I had to add "from dual" in order for it to become valid SQL).